# Using Net::HTTP to POST Json data to remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, net-http

I'm Using ruby on rails and for some reason the remote server doesn't accept the format of my data, I want to make sure nothing else is wrong with with my code:

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code with following and it's returning data, you can ignore the line `request.body` or you can use it, in both cases it will return you the response.
`uri=URI.parse('https://mkpartners.secure.force.com/services/apexrest/careers?firstName=ss&lastName=dd&email=pp@ss.com')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

request.body =JSON.pretty_generate(data)
response = http.request(request)`

The issue with the return value they are returning HTML, when you will try to prase the response using `JSON.parse(response.body)`, it's throwing error.you need to confirm with other team that they should return json.

Comment: But 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules, in other words the Json sent is invalid, the question is the Json data I'm sending is formatted correctly or not?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was a webservice problem.